# How can i pass new keys in eb init command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I run this command and it asked for the access key and secret access key.

```
eb init -p python-3.7 -r us-east-2 barebone-flask-rest-api
```

but I got error - **User:  is not authorized to perform: elasticbeanstalk: CreateApplication on resource**

I created a new user with the desired permission.

And run the command again. But this time it is not asking for keys. and using the old ones on it's own. How can I pass new keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you added the new user's profile under new name to your AWS credentials file, then you have to **explicitly** specify the [--profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-cmd-options.html) name. For example:

```
eb init -p python-3.7 -r us-east-2 barebone-flask-rest-api --profile new-user
```

Comment: tried that, but it gave me new error - ERROR: InvalidProfileError - The config profile (rest-api) could not be found. This user is present in AWS IAM.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal Have you set it up using `aws configure` or manually added its keys to `~/.aws/credentaials`?

Comment: There is no such file in my environment.

Comment: Can  check  [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration-multi-profiles) for how to setup an aws cli with multiple profiles.

Comment: @DeveshAgrawal It should be `~/.aws/credentials`. Made a spelling mistake in the file's name before. Sorry.